# How can i loop through a script?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have loads of tables in my mysql database:

The following script takes the table and dumps it into my mssql database.

```
SELECT * INTO testMySQL.dbo.userDetails
FROM openquery(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM test.userDetails')
```

But how would i loop through every table....

i followed the following guide:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/migrate-mysql-to-mssql.aspx?fid=1526183&fr=51#xx0xx

Comment: There is no way for MSSQL to incept a mysqldump file?

Comment: What about linked server? This way, you can have access from SQL Server to MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Use openquery to read information schema from mysql then write a cursor to read all tables you got from information schema.

Comment: I doubt the OP knows what a Cursor is considering he used the term loop. You should post an example of how this would look.

Comment: He can "loop" in his preferred language, it doesn't have to be t-sql. I'm not giving him the fish, I'm teaching him to fish :)

Comment: How does one even understand what Cursor is if i dont have an example. Why are you locking away you're knowledge? This is not my idea of a community.

Comment: If you're using mssql and you don't know what a cursor is you should stop whatever you're developing and spend some time on google...